# Unable to create sed substitution to deduplicate file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the file with many duplicates of the form

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Which I need to reduce to

```
a
b
c
```

So I wrote a sed command: `sed -r 's/^(.*)$\n^(.*)$/\1/mg' filename`, but the file was still showing duplicates. However I'm sure this regex works because I tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/iP8rR6/1).

So what am I doing wrong?

I suspect it may be related to the `-r` option, as I'm not really sure what that does (but without it I get a `invalid reference \1 on`s' command's RHS` error).

Comment: What is the expected result with: `a\na\nb\na\na`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `a\nb\na`

Comment: Is the file always already sorted? If so, use `uniq`. If not and the resulting file is permitted to be in sorted (not original) order, you can use `sort -u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of 2 simpler approaches should work for you.

A simple `awk` command to print a line only first time by maintaining an array of already printed lines:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
a
b
c
```

Since file is already sorted you can use `uniq` also:

```
uniq file
a
b
c
```

---

**Edit:** Newer gnu-awk versions support in place editing also using:

```
awk -i 'inplace' '!seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: Probably not but newer `awk` versions have option for in place editing.